# "On duplicate key update" in recursive query using gorm updates only parent_id field for the child record

Tags: duplicates, grails-orm, children

The below is golang struct for the table where settings will be stored recursively.

```
// Settings table in database
type Settings struct {
    ID          uint       `json:"id"`
    Name        string     `json:"name"`
    Value       string     `json:"value"`
    Parent_ID   uint       `json:"parent_id" gorm:"default:null"`
    Description string     `json:"description"`
    Parent      *Settings  `gorm:"foreignKey:Parent_ID"`
    Children    []Settings `gorm:"foreignKey:Parent_ID" json:"Children"`
}
```

When Passing the below json to db.Save(&settings) to update the settings table which already has parent record with ID 30 and its child record with ID 31, on duplicate key updates works fine for parent record.

```
[
    {
        "id": 30,
        "name": "seal",
        "value": "XXXX.png",
        "parent_id": 0,
        "description": "",
        "Parent": null,
        "Children": [
            {
                "id": 31,
                "name": "sealcontent",
                "value": "test data dddd",
                "parent_id": 0,
                "description": "Child Description 2-1",
                "Parent": null,
                "Children": null
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The issue is for child record as it only updates parent_id for the child row. Corresponding sql query generated by gorm is given below.

INSERT INTO `settings` (`name`,`value`,`description`,`parent_id`,`id`) VALUES *('sealcontent','test data dddd','Child Description 2-1',30,31) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `parent_id`=VALUES(`parent_id`)*

Please help me how to achieve the below query for child record updates on duplicate key case so that new vales for all the fields can be updated.

INSERT INTO `settings` (`name`,`value`,`description`,`parent_id`,`id`) VALUES ('sealcontent','test data dddd','Child Description 2-1',30,31) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `parent_id`=`name`=VALUES(`name`),`value`=VALUES(`value`),`description`=VALUES(`description`),VALUES(`parent_id`)

In Summary

What I am getting now for child record update
INSERT INTO `settings` (`name`,`value`,`description`,`parent_id`,`id`) VALUES *('sealcontent','test data dddd','Child Description 2-1',30,31) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `parent_id`=VALUES(`parent_id`)*

How I need

INSERT INTO `settings` (`name`,`value`,`description`,`parent_id`,`id`) VALUES ('sealcontent','test data dddd','Child Description 2-1',30,31) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `parent_id`=`name`=VALUES(`name`),`value`=VALUES(`value`),`description`=VALUES(`description`),VALUES(`parent_id`